# How to select value from a dropdown using JScript (not JavaScript) with TestComplete for a silverlight web application

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I am using TestComplete to automate our regression for a silverlight web app, so we have multiple forms in the system and plenty of dropdowns and I am able to click on the dropdown combobox but unable to select any items from the dropdown list using ClickItem() or selectedIndex() method even when i have mapped one the imtem just to isolate it and try that way.

Does any one know how I can pick the correct value by passing it through using ClickItem method?

TIA

Comment: If there is an advanced support for this specific control, you can just record the needed action using TestComplete and you will see the right syntax. Do you have problems with this?

Comment: Yes - as with recording scripts, issue I have is our product is UI intensive and early stage which means there are new changes on UI side which menas I have to keep re-recording the script- so its easier for me to specify values and point it to the object names which remains constant. Also I have been able to use SelectedIndex() now by calling the Combo box list object and got the index by exporting them using a sql script and as most of the regression test cases had repetitive values I needed to select - made it much easier.

Cheers